# Insert or "squirt" text into Iframe automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

When an iframe is displayed I'd like some text or html written to it without intervention.

This does what I need, however, you must click a button for the contents to be written to the iframe.

Is there a way to alter this so that no click is needed? "[extended_description]" is just written in the iframe without clicking on the input button?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doThing() {
    var e = document.getElementById("stepsAchieved");
    e.contentWindow.document.write("[extended_description]"), e.contentWindow.document.close()
}   
</script>
<input type="button" value="Click To Insert Text" onclick="doThing();return false;" id="fred" />
<hr />
<iframe src="" id="stepsAchieved" name="garminStepsAchieved" frameborder="1" height="200px" width="340px" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

Comment: Is the iframe running on your domain?

Comment: I have ecommerce descriptions that are made by the mfg. So everyone uses the exact same description on the net. To avoid duplicate content issues, it has been suggested to just put the dynamically generated description in an iframe on the item page so google doesn't think it is on that page. So the source of the iframe will be empty or null, and I need the template tag to generate the text description to be in an iframe. I don't know if that answers your question. I'm not really pulling a page from elsewhere, I'm trying to just have the product description in an iframe.

Comment: lol so you're concerned with Google's data storage limits?

Comment: No, I'm concerned with 100's of other people selling the same item on the internet containing the exact same text on their web pages as well. Everyone has duplicate content.  It's not as easy as re-writing a few product descriptions.... there are over 30,000. So I'm trying to present the product paragraph description for the customer to read, but for google not to see as residing on that page when it is crawled.

Answer (score 0):

**OK** taking this from another direction that I wanted to earlier but got distracted til now.

Making the iFrame on-the-fly to ensure Javascript can access it.

### [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/LcuCn/)

```
var steps = document.createElement('iframe');
var description = '[extended_description]';
steps.src = 'Javascript:"' + description + '"';
steps.id = 'stepsAchieved';
steps.name = 'garminStepsAchieved';
steps.setAttribute('frameborder', '1');
steps.height = 200;
steps.width = 340;
steps.setAttribute('scrolling', 'auto');
document.getElementById('description').appendChild(steps);
```

Comment: Ok, so what happens if the iframe with ID="stepsAchieved" is located inside an element with a class= or id=?       <div id="description"><iframe id="stepsAchieved"></iframe></div>    I can't get it to work in this context......

Comment: What part of your HTML did you put this script in?

Comment: The script and iframe id="stepsAchieved" are located within a div with the id="description".

Comment: Put the script at the end of your HTML's `<body>`

Comment: Still not working. Doesn't seem to be finding the element id="stepsAchieved" perhaps?

Comment: @blademan updated with example of it working, different approach entirely hope it's something you can use

Comment: So simply place that script within  <div id="description"></div>?

Comment: I would place it after that `<div>` to make sure the DOM has loaded it in time for the iFrame to be appended inside

Comment: PS - I mimicked your original iFrame attributes exactly but I would recommend using `frameborder=0` instead of `1` so it blends into your page seamlessly.

Comment: Saw it work on jsfiddle. It seems to be working basically on my web page..... and if I look at source I see  <div itemprop="description" id="description">
<iframe name="garminStepsAchieved" id="stepsAchieved" src="Javascript:&quot;The wording of the item description.&quot;" scrolling="auto" width="340" frameborder="1" height="200">
</iframe>
</div>        But the iframe is blank.  src=  is actually not displaying any text in the iframe on my web page.

Comment: Hang on, let me try it after as you suggest.

Comment: No, no change.  The iframe gets produced with src="Javascript:"blahblah" but nothing is visible to the eye inside the iframe on the web page.

Comment: Can't you actually have an HTML page on your server that's something like /product_descriptions/product?id=325325 and just include this, then block that directory via robots.txt and with no-index headers? It's more reliable than including the content on the page via JS, since sometimes Google may execute JS when crawling a page

Comment: You can't block it without blocking the whole page from being crawled so he'd lose business.  And @blademan I put the code into a new HTML file (not in fiddle) and threw it on my server with success.  View it and its source here:  http://www.fleeceitout.com/frame.html

Comment: Deryck, actually I'm still suggesting that he use an iframe for the no-index content, just not all this JS business to try to hide the contents of the iframe. Btw, I meant to post the comment on the original question, not this answer in particular... my bad.

Comment: @Deryck I did same on my server here. A simple little file like that works. However, when I place the code on my shopping cart template, nothing displays inside the iframe even though the src= has text in it. I don't know if perhaps it is because id="description" is buried on the page deeper inside some outer divs with classes and ids or what. But all I get is an empty iframe border when viewing the product page.

Comment: wrap my code in a `setTimeout(function() { ... }, 500);` Use chrome dev tools and see what kind of page load time you get and adjust the timeout to wait about that long.  500 should be a decent starter limit